# Why TFileStream.write produces incorrect data? Dephi 7

Tags: delphi, filestreams, tfilestream

I tried to create a function/method which should write to a file with 
a header filled with zeros

```
header := StringOfChar(char(0), 11*offsetSize);
```

But when I check the file which was created, it has the following values (hex):

```
C026A200160000000100000006000000264C656B63650000B2000000B04D45005C1EA200306CA20000000000
```

I expected the output file should contain

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Then I also tried to fill it with `chr(1)` and the result was similar:

```
C026A200160000000100000006000000264C656B63650000B2000000B04D45005C1EA200306CA20000000000
```

(It looks the same).

When I debug in Delphi 7, I watch the header when it is filled with zeros:

```
#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0
```

When I fill it with `chr(1)` then it contains...

```
#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1
```

So my question is, why is this happening? What am I doing wrong that the output file contains the wrong data?

```
unit Dictionary_io;

interface

uses
  Classes, Windows, SysUtils, Dialogs;

const
  offsetTableEntriesCount = 10;

type
  TCountType = dword;
  TOffsetType = dword;
  TTextType = ANSIString;

const
  testItemsCount = 1;

type
  Dictionary = class
  private
    fsInput, fsOutput: TFileStream;
    fileName: string;
    msOffsets: TMemoryStream;
    offsetSize: TOffsetType;
    ofsTableEntries: TCountType;
    lng: integer;
    itemsCount: byte;
    header: TTextType;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure dicRewrite;
  end;

implementation

constructor Dictionary.Create;
begin
  offsetSize := sizeof(offsetSize);
end;

procedure Dictionary.dicRewrite;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  itemsCount := 0;
  header := StringOfChar(char(0), 11*offsetSize);
  try
    fileName := 'A:\test.bin';
    if FileExists(fileName) then
      DeleteFile(fileName);
    fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
    try
      fsOutput.Write(header,Length(header));
    finally
    end;
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason your data is not being written to the file correctly is because you are not passing the `header` to `Write()` correctly.  `Write()` takes an untyped `var` as input, and you are passing it the `header` variable as-is, so you are passing `Write()` the memory address of `header` itself.  But a `string` contains a pointer to character data that is stored elsewhere in memory.  So, in order to write that data to your file, you need to dereference the `string` pointer so you pass in the memory address of the character data instead.

Also, if you do not want to check the return value of `Write()` for errors, you should use `WriteBuffer()` instead.

Try this:

```
procedure Dictionary.dicRewrite;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  itemsCount := 0;
  header := StringOfChar(#0, 11*offsetSize);
  fileName := 'A:\test.bin';
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    fsOutput.WriteBuffer(header[1], Length(header));
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure Dictionary.dicRewrite;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  itemsCount := 0;
  header := StringOfChar(#0, 11*offsetSize);
  fileName := 'A:\test.bin';
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    fsOutput.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(header)^, Length(header));
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, you really should not be using a `string` for binary data (especially if you ever plan on upgrading your project to Delphi 2009+.  You should use a `record` or an array of bytes instead, eg:

```
private
  header: array of Byte;

procedure Dictionary.dicRewrite;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  itemsCount := 0;
  SetLength(header, 11*offsetSize);
  FillChar(header[0], Length(header), #0);
  fileName := 'A:\test.bin';
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    fsOutput.WriteBuffer(header[0], Length(header));
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure Dictionary.dicRewrite;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  itemsCount := 0;
  SetLength(header, 11*offsetSize);
  FillChar(PByte(header)^, Length(header), #0);
  fileName := 'A:\test.bin';
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    fsOutput.WriteBuffer(PByte(header)^, Length(header));
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
private
  header: array[0..(11*offsetSize)-1] of Byte;

procedure Dictionary.dicRewrite;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  itemsCount := 0;
  FillChar(header, Length(header), #0);
  fileName := 'A:\test.bin';
  fsOutput := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  try
    fsOutput.WriteBuffer(header, SizeOf(header));
  finally
    fsOutput.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Should use WriteBuffer rather than Write, if you aren't going to check the return value for errors.